# What is the adjoint of the operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, hilbert-space

What is the adjoint of the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$in quantum mechanics? 
I think the answer should be $\frac{d}{dx}$ because it has no imaginary term.

Comment: What is the *definition* of adjoint?

Comment: actually, what of $p=-i\hbar d/dx$?  Is it not Hermitian (or self-adjoint) and it has an imaginary part...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $- \frac{d}{dx}$. Of course there are subleties about the domain, but this is physics. To show the result you get the minus from.the partial integration.

Comment: How did you do that? Could you please explain?

Comment: The subtleties you speak of show up in the first system ever presented to physics students, so they are worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of wave functions, we have (for $p=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$)
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \phi(x)^* \left(\hat p \psi(x)\right)&=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \phi(x)^* \left(-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)\right)\, ,\\
&= -i\hbar\phi^*(x)\psi(x)\Bigl\vert_{-\infty}^\infty-(-i\hbar)
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \left(\frac{d}{dx}\phi(x)\right)^* \psi(x) 
\end{align}
using integration by parts.  It is an *assumption* that $\psi(\pm\infty)\to 0$ so this removes the boundary term and we're left with 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \phi(x)^* \left(\hat p \psi(x)\right)=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \left(-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}\phi(x)\right)^* \psi(x) 
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \left(\hat p\phi(x)\right)^* \psi(x) \, .
$$
This shows that $\hat p=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$, with the condition $\psi(\pm\infty)\to 0$, is hermitian (or its own adjoint).  There are subtleties tied technical issues but with "reasonable" functions this will work.

You can work out by yourself what happens for $\frac{d}{dx}$ given the discussion on $\hat p$.  Moreover, it is *very good* to reflect on the assumption $\psi(\pm\infty)\to 0$ and other technicalities in the context of for instance [this discussion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0103153.pdf) on the quantum infinite well.